# Java, Spring internationalization: how to use values from .properties in simple String?

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc

I use the next code

```
@Value("${app.user.root}")
    private String userRoot;
```

to get constant value from my **application.properties** file.

In my `GetMapping method` I need to redirect to the **error** page and to pass a String as parameter.

```
@GetMapping("/user/activate")
    public String activate(String activation) {
        Users u = usersService.activate(activation);
        if (u != null) {
            usersService.autoLogin(u);
            return "redirect:/";
        }

        return "redirect:/error?message=Could not activate with this activation code, please contact support";
```

But I need to have different String values with different languages. So, I am using Spring i18n, but how can I get the value I need at runtime? I need something like this:

```
return "redirect:/error?message=${errorMessage}";
```

Thank you, hope you will help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you have to create multiple properties file for multiple languages

`messages_en.properties`
`messages_fr.properties`

The configuration of i18n should be following

```
@Configuration
public class LanguageConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource(){
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }
    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SmartLocaleResolver slr = new SmartLocaleResolver();
    Locale locale = new Locale("en", "us");
    slr.setDefaultLocale(locale); // Set default Locale as en_cos
        return slr;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor interceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        interceptor.setParamName("lang");
        return interceptor;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeInterceptor());
    }

    class SmartLocaleResolver extends CookieLocaleResolver {

        @Override
        public Locale resolveLocale(HttpServletRequest request) {
            String acceptLanguage = request.getHeader("Accept-Language");
            if (acceptLanguage == null || acceptLanguage.trim().isEmpty()) {
                return super.determineDefaultLocale(request);
            }
            return request.getLocale();
        }

    }
}
```

Now update your controller code and autowire `org.springframework.context.MessageSource` and then use it to get localized message.

```
@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;
```

Then you can get the localized message using following code.

```
String errorMessage = messageSource.getMessage("project.errorMessage", new Object[]{"John Doe"},  LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
```

You can also use Locale object from controller method parameter instead of LocaleContextHolder.getLocale(), but it works just fine.